# Changing ntext column type to varchar(n) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem when converting all table columns with `ntext` type in my database. I wrote this query in order to alter my columns, but there is a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn 
VARCHAR(SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(mycolumn)) FROM  mytable);
```

Even though `SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(mycolumn)) FROM mytable` is returning the correct number, the query cannot be executed.

The syntax error is:

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.(which is inside the
>   `varchar`)*

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `ntext` to `varchar` might cause data loss, Do you need  `nvarchar`?

Comment: Hi Martin, Yes I'm trying to convert from `ntext` to `varchar(max_of_length_of_column)` all columns in my table. How data loss happens in my case?

Comment: Because `ntext` is double byte and `varchar` is (under most collations) single byte so not all characters can be represented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to execute this as dynamic sql because the size of the column cannot be a variable.

```
DECLARE @Length int = SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(mycolumn)) FROM mytable
DECLARE @MyTable varchar(100) = 'mytable'
DECLARE @MyColumn varchar(100) = 'mycolumn'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000) = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @MyTable +' ALTER COLUMN '+ @MyColumn +' VARCHAR(' + CONVERT(varchar, @Length) + ')'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

The benefit of this is you could loop over `sys.objects` and `sys.columns` to find all ntext columns and convert them to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you cannot do this inside an `ALTER COLUMN` statement. At least I've never seen this.

You should do this way:

Calculate the max data length in that column (you're already doing this):

```
SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(mycolumn)) FROM mytable
```

Now just replace the value you got in the previous query:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR(MAXVALUEFROMPREVIOUSQUERY);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I cannot do as you told. Because query should be dynamic, I cannot do it for my database which has lots of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Trying:

```
SET @maxLength = SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(mycolumn)) FROM mytable;

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR(@maxLength);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Zenofo, but I had tried such method already. But it didn't work as well.

Comment: Checkout @james-curtis's answer,using `DECLARE` and `EXEC` to run SQL query